# How to create PDF with Multiple Languages (English, German) dynamically using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using the DOMPDF library to create PDF. This document can be in English, German or Spanish dynamically. How can i achieve this with DOMPDF?

Can i get any help?

thanks.

Comment: You won't get much help with this, sorry. This place offers help with _specific_ coding issues you cannot solve _in your own code_. This is _not_ a tutorial site or similar.

Comment: Not natively in dompdf. You would need to process the requested language in your code prior to feeding the HTML to dompdf. [This seems on-point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970095/how-to-create-pdf-with-multiple-languages-english-german-dynamically-using-do#comment55698149_33970504).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert html to pdf, use utf-8 encoding like the below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-family: firefly, verdana, sans-serif;">
      Spanish: El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofóndetrás del palenque de paja.
    </p>
    <p style="font-family: firefly, verdana, sans-serif;">
      German: Victor jagt zwölf Boxkämpfer quer über den großen Sylter Deich
    </p>
    <p style="font-family: firefly, verdana, sans-serif;">
      English: The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am asking like jquery localization. is there any method like this in dompdf?

Comment: Jquery runs in client side. Not sure if dompdf have localization function. You can achieve localization in php using http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php 
Then you will have to club it with dompdf.